# Accounting T-Account scheme

Tags: tables

I would like to create a T-account as the ones represented in this image:

[image]

I have tried to do this using the table environment, without good results (when for example I have words/numbers only on one side of the account, say left, all the space on the other side (right) is removed).

Maybe a workable solution is to use the `minipage` environment with two columns inside?

Any advice appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
%\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Statement of Income 2015} \\ \hline
Debit                     & Credit             \\ \hline
Increase                  & Decrease           \\ \hline
Normal Balance            &                    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be good to provide a working example code (especially so since you have attempted it already), so that we can help you improve on it, or otherwise suggest a better alternative.

Comment: This is pretty easy with a `\multicolumn`  approach and wrapping column types

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Could you please further develop my MWE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(edited to take into account the OP's wish to be able to override the default width of a t-account)

Here's an answer that defines a macro, called `\taccount`, which takes four arguments, the first of which is optional:

- the width of each t-column; this argument is optional. If left unspecified
  it will default to `\tcolumnwidth` (set to `1.75cm` in the code below)
- the account header (centered, automatic line-wrapping enabled)
- the material for the left-hand ("asset") column (ragged-right, line-wrapping enabled, hyphenation is allowed)
- the material for the right-hand ("liability") column (also ragged-right, line-wrapping enabled, hyphenation is allowed)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newlength\tcolumnwidth
\setlength\tcolumnwidth{1.75cm} % default width of t-column
\newlength\taccountwidth

%% The macro "\taccount" takes 4 arguments. The first
%% arg. is optional; its default value is \tcolumnwidth.
\newcommand\taccount[4][\tcolumnwidth]{% 
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333} % default value: 1
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}         % default value: 6pt
  \setlength\taccountwidth{\dimexpr#1+#1+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth\relax}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l|l@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{>{\Centering}p{\taccountwidth}}{#2}\\
  \hline
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} 
  #3 \end{tabular} 
  &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}@{}} 
  #4 \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
% First instance of \taccount uses the default width;
% the second instance uses a non-default width.
\taccount{A basic T-account}
  {Asset 1\\Asset 2\\Asset 3\\Asset 4}
  {Liability 1\\Liability 2\\ Equity}
\qquad     
\taccount[2.75cm]{A slightly more complicated T-account}
  {Basic Asset 1\\Complicated Asset 2\\Asset 3\\Asset 4}
  {Liability 1\\Complicated Liability 2\\Preferred Stock\\Common Equity}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the width for a single T-Account? By putting the TaccountWidth in the preamble it influences all the T-scheme created in the document with a fixed width. I would like to change it arbitrarily with respect to the content of each T-Accounts.

Comment: @FrancescoBianchi - I've modified the code of the `\taccount` macro so that it takes an additional, optional argument, viz., the width of each t-column.

Answer (score 5):

The definition below introduces the macro

```
\Taccount[column width]{headline}{table contents}
```

The first argument is optional and defaults to `1.5cm`.

```
\newcommand\Taccount[3][1.5cm]%
   {{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{#1}|p{#1}@{}}
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{#2}\\
    \hline
    #3
    \end{tabular}%
   }}
```

The spacing between rows is controlled by `\arraystretch`, which is increased here to `1.3`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Taccount[3][1.5cm]%
   {{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{#1}|p{#1}@{}}
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{#2}\\
    \hline
    #3
    \end{tabular}%
   }}
\begin{document}
\Taccount{Assets}{Debits&Credits\\Increase&Decrease\\Normal Balance}\quad
\Taccount{Expenses}{Debits&Credits\\Increase&Decrease\\Normal Balance}\quad
\Taccount{Owner's Drawing}{Debits&Credits\\Increase&Decrease\\Normal Balance}
\bigskip

\Taccount{Liabilities}{Debits&Credits\\Decrease&Increase\\&Normal Balance}\quad
\Taccount{Revenues}{Debits&Credits\\Decrease&Increase\\&Normal Balance}\quad
\Taccount{Owner's Capital}{Debits&Credits\\Decrease&Increase\\&Normal Balance}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the width for a single T-Account? By putting the TaccountWidth in the preamble it influences all the T-scheme created in the document with a fixed width. I would like to change it arbitrarily with respect to the content of each T-Accounts.

Comment: @FrancescoBianchi I've added an optional parameter for the width of the columns. In fact, this makes the definition a bit simpler.