# advanced T-account sample

Tags: tables

I would like to generate a "newcommand" to generate T-accounts for a thesis (like in the attached picture) but cannot get the table done. So far I have used the idea from here [Accounting T-Account scheme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351403/accounting-t-account-scheme) but it's not quite it. 
Especially the aligned design of 3 columns in the header whereas below there are 4 columns somehow eludes me. Can somebody give me a hint how to achieve this?

merci A

[image]

Comment: Are `T` accounts still really used nowadays? I remember this almost 30 years back in school ... never needed them later on. Basically, it is nothing else than a tabular with several columns, the problem is the asynchronous filling of the left and right halves of the table

Comment: yes, they are still valid; there is no better way to illustrate the  mechanics behind booking entries. The problem today is that most people try to skip this knowledge and become mere user of bookeeping software ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
{\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllr|lllr@{}}
Dr & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Bank} & Cr \\
\hline 
&&& \$ &&&& \$ \\
Apr & 1 & Balance b/f &4{,}300 & Apr & 9 & Baking equipment & 12{,}000 \\
......
\end{tabular}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Taccount}{m}
 {
  \str_clear:N \l__aerioeus_taccount_lmonth_str
  \str_clear:N \l__aerioeus_taccount_rmonth_str
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \aerioeus_taccount_entry:n
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\makebox[0pt][l]{Dr}\hfill Bank\hfill\makebox[0pt][r]{Cr}}
  \\
  \hline
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{~}r@{~}lr}
  &&&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\$}\\
  \l__aerioeus_taccount_left_tl
  \end{tabular}
  &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{~}r@{~}lr@{}}
  &&&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\$}\\
  \l__aerioeus_taccount_right_tl
  \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__aerioeus_taccount_left_tl
\tl_new:N \l__aerioeus_taccount_right_tl
\str_new:N \l__aerioeus_taccount_lmonth_str
\str_new:N \l__aerioeus_taccount_rmonth_str

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aerioeus_taccount_entry:n
 {
  \__aerioeus_taccount_entry:n #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aerioeus_taccount_entry:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {+}{ \__aerioeus_taccount_entry:NNnnnn \l__aerioeus_taccount_left_tl \l__aerioeus_taccount_lmonth_str }
    {-}{ \__aerioeus_taccount_entry:NNnnnn \l__aerioeus_taccount_right_tl \l__aerioeus_taccount_rmonth_str }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aerioeus_taccount_entry:NNnnnn
 {% #1 = tl, #2 = str, #3 = month, #4 = day, #5 = desc, #6 = amount
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { #3 } { #2 }
   {% month is the same as the previous entry
    \tl_put_right:Nn #1 { & #4 & #5 & #6 \\ }
   }
   {% months differ, update the current one
    \str_set:Nn #2 { #3 }
    \tl_put_right:Nn #1 { #3 & #4 & #5 & #6 \\ }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\Taccount{
  +{Apr}{1}{Balance b/f}{4,300},
  +{Apr}{1}{Capital}{15,000},
  +{Apr}{7}{Loan}{5,000},
  -{Apr}{9}{Baking equipment}{12,000},
  -{Apr}{15}{Drawing}{500},
  +{Apr}{17}{Services rendered}{10,500},
  +{Apr}{19}{Debtors}{5,000},
  -{Apr}{19}{Salaries}{4,000},
  -{May}{13}{Creditors}{200},
  -{May}{13}{Loan}{4,000},
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

As you see, entries for the left column are marked `+`, for the right column `-` and are entered sequentially. The comma at the end of a line is essential.

Each entry is examined: the `+` or `-` decide whether the remaining four arguments are added to the left or right subtable. After collecting the data, the table is output.

[image]

Comment: Merci, @egreg very sophisticated! I need to digest that tomorrow and might get back with a question or 2...